# Is it possible to fix problems with relative imports?

Tags: python-3.x, relative-import

I have some problems with import mechanic. For example I have a tree like this:

```
├── my_package  
|   ├── first.py  
|   └── second.py  
└── test.py
```

second.py:

```
def second_func():
    print('Hello World')
```

first.py:

```
from second import second_func

def first_func():
    second_func()
```

test.py:

```
from my_package.first import first_func

first_func()
```

And when I try to run `test.py` I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'second'
```

It feels like `second.py` is not searched in `my_package`, but in the directory where `my_pacakage` and `test.py` are located. This is a strange mechanics, because if I have a ready-made package, I don’t want to create some new file in it, I want to interact with it from another place.

Comment: create `__init__.py` file in `my_package`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a `__init__.py` in the `my_package`. Change import statement of the `first.py` to the following

`from .second import second_func`

Then run `python test.py`. It should give `Hello World`